# Send and validate UTF 8 via request in Angular via PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, utf-8

How could I send an `UTF`  request like data `string` or `array`, 
for example, Korean or Japanese language 
Now it sends a wired `string` like `:exe34343exe3435`

request example:

```
 var params = {
                id:id,
            };
            return $http({
                method: "POST",
                url:("services.php"),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                timeout: "2000ms",
                data: $.param({action:"get_test", data: params}),
            })
                .then(getFun)
                .catch(function(message) {
                    throw new Error("XHR Failed",message);
                });
```

`PHP` does not know how to work with the string

For now Im using

```
$this->test = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'test', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
```

but if the `string` is in `UTF`- Like Chinese or Japanese it converts it to something like: `%EX234234`...

so what is the best way to validate my inputs in `UTF-8`

Comment: You could try to add `'charset' : 'utf-8'` to the headers. You should just be able to send any UTF using a POST..

Comment: in the request is OK but the PHP does not convert it